# 1 fixed background + 1 tiled background in CSS

Tags: css

My target is that a spider is going down it's web in the background. 
I need the web image (a simple vertical line) to tile above the spider, while the spider image sits at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two background images on the same element.

Simply, create a `div` right inside your `body` that takes full width and height. Then use the tiled background in one of them (the `div`, I assume) an the fixed background in the other (the `body`, I assume).

Watch out for margins and padding across browsers, though!

Comment: I'm trying this now but I'm not getting any results. 
Here is my CSS http://pastebin.org/117761
(just posting a pastebin since i can't get markdown to work)

Comment: Send in the HTML too, and the CSS for the `body`.

Comment: body css http://pastebin.org/117770
html http://pastebin.org/117771
the <div id="background-image"> is way there at the bottom

Comment: The inner div has to contain all your page: `<body><div id="bg-img">(... remaining of your HTML ...)</div></body>`.

Answer (score 1):

WebKit (Safari, Chrome) does allow multiple backgrounds; just seperate them with commas.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you put "the spider" as fixed background image for your `<body>` tag and put "the web" as a background image (with repeat) for a div set to `{ width: 100%; }`